# Intersection of two vector tables data in postgresql

Tags: postgis, raster, postgresql, polygon, vector

I have satellite raster data that is converted into pixels using

```
CREATE TABLE gtru_tile_pix AS SELECT 
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast)).val,
    (ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast)).geom
FROM gtru_tile_raster;
```

and I have vector data (polygons) in other layer to get sample pixels from the above pixels.

Please tell me 
How to get the intersection of two tables?

Answer (score 1):

the pixels that fall within the polygon, and get the sum of the pixel value

```
CREATE TABLE gtur_srtm_inter AS
SELECT id, 
    (gv).geom AS the_geom, 
    (gv).val
FROM (SELECT id, 
             ST_Intersection(rast, the_geom) AS gv
      FROM srtm_tiled,
           gtru_poly_vect
      WHERE ST_Intersects(rast, the_geom)
     ) foo;
```

The values were then summarized using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE result01 AS
SELECT id, 
       sum(ST_Area(ST_Transform(the_geom, 32198)) * val) / 
       sum(ST_Area(ST_Transform(the_geom, 32198))) AS meanelev
FROM gtru_srtm_inter
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```